# Have to reboot router to make it work properly on specific devices

Tags: wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, reboot, speed

I have a Linksys router (WRT610N ver 2.0) that I never hard problem with in the last 2-3 years, until 2 days ago. Sometimes(often after a reboot or a wake up) my laptop wont connect at all, or connect with a weak signal strenght(while im 2 feet away from it) to the router(and with about 1-2mbps download speed--im supposed to have 15mbps).I does the same on my PS4(PS4 is able to connect by connection speed is slower than usual).However, no problem on my iPod, the WiFi connection speed on it is normal.All these device are wirelessly connected over WiFi on the router.I noticed that if I unplug the router for a bit(few seconds), then plug it back on, it does solve the problem and the WiFi speed come back to normal on all my device.Then if I go to sleep(turn laptop and PS4 off), the next day I have to unplug the router again because the issue came back.I never had this problem before.I dont know if I can get any help on that?

Thank you!

Comment: Linksys/Cisco seems to have this problem where Apple devices work perfectly while a reboot is required for Windows to work. I have never been able to figure it out, but it seems that Linksys' quality has gone down to the level where its technology can no longer run for more than 24 hours without a reboot.

Comment: Well like I said, the thing is that I had no problems at all during the past 2 years.This problem only started 2 days ago for no reason.When I bought it, the WRT610N was considered a high quality router(paid 150$ for it)

Comment: Same thing with my Cisco, $200 router. They work until the warranty expires and then cease to function.

Comment: Well what should I do now? My router still work when I unplug and replug it.It just that I have to unplug it again after a few hours.Should I reset it to factory settings and set it all over again?

Comment: That might help, but I doubt it. I say invest in an older G router from Linksys

Comment: Why would I want a slower old router?!

Comment: If you're doing network transfers, chances are they're between computers, in which case LAN should be used. Besides, G is fast enough for your Internet speed, so there's no problem there. Maybe make two WiFi networks: keep the N and set up a G to connect to with Windows.

Comment: I use my router to connect my laptop and PS4 wirelessly to it and access internet, play online,etc... Same for my iPod.Im in an apartment, my PS4 is about 5 feet away from router, laptop is maybe 10 feet away(or less).

Comment: Just connect them with ethernet, then.

Comment: Thats the point why I want a router; to be able to connect wirelessly

Comment: What's the point, though? Even N is worse than ethernet, especially with online games.